# how to create sql server trigger and call it in mvc3 model

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I have four tables ie.

- custAddress
- custCompany
- custContact and
- custInfo

All of the table has **'cId'** field common.

I have a interface in MVC3 view from which I will take inputs for all field except 'cId'. When I take input from the interface all of the above tables must be filled.

Also when I delete data, once I delete data from one table all the data from the other three table should be deleted.

I don't know how to use trigger for this. Please explain how can I do this using trigger or any other way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure thst you need trigger? Why don't you want to insert data to all 3 tables manually and use cascade delete on removing data? Triggers are powerfull but have some disadvantages: you can't unit test it, business logic spreads into several layers. i think it's to simple case to use them.

Comment: can you probide me with some coding examples

Comment: What example? How to update tables in sql server? We still don't know how you access DB, have you got Orm for example?

Comment: I use stored procedure to insert. should I use 4 stored procedure or one is sufficient?

Comment: Surely, you must use one stored procedure. And no trieggers for this scenario, it's common for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds more like a database design problem. You do not need trigger here. Keep one of your table as primary (may be CustInfo) and have other table dependent(foreign key relationships) on this. Use cascade delete constraints on dependent tables.  When you delete data from CustInfo, cascade delete constraint will take care of deleting corresponding data from dependent tables.

Comment: can you povide me with some coding examples